# Read configuration variables from configurationJson

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm using launchSettings.json and eventually another json, to put my configuration variables.

At first, I would read from launchSettings.json information such as address:port where I'm exposing my endpoint.

Then I'd use another json (appSettings.json), to put some configuration variables, such it could be the name of the application, or some connection's rules.

I've tried to add an `IConfiguration` to the singleton context, and then I used into my service. Into the controller, I wasn't able to read nothing from the json:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();

   services.AddOpenApiDocument();

   services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

and this is the constructor of my service:

```
public ExampleService(IConfiguration Iconfiguration)
{
   configuration = Iconfiguration;
   configuration.GetValue<string>("port");
}
```

> appSettings.json {   "address": "127.0.0.1",   "port": 8080,
>
> "configuration": {
>
> ```
> "address": "http://localhost",
> "port": 8081   } }
> ```

For example from the constructor, or in another method, i can't retrieve nothing from the appSettings.json

What should be the right configuration?

Here is the repo's url:
https://osharkokun.visualstudio.com/_git/Client-Server

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, you should be getting the instance of `IConfiguration` in `Startup` constructor like

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Then if you have a configuration section defined like below

```
"portconfig": 
{
"address": "http://localhost",
"port": 8081   
}
```

You get that config section

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.Configure<portconfig>(Configuration.GetSection("portconfig"));
}
```

Read documentation for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Per your **comment**: you can read any configuration using the `Configuration` property like

```
this.Configuration["Your_config_key"]
```

Comment: and if i want to load the configuration used in launcherSettings.json for start the application?

Comment: @osharko launchSettings.json is really a file used in debugging, not something you should be reading in your app.

Comment: Rahul, for example if i do → this.Configuration["profiles"] in Startup class, i receive a null.
i'm working in asp.net 3.0. should it be a problem?

Comment: @DavidG oh, i see. but if i want to have the localhost:port saved into a file that the application read on startup, and that i can read for recursively rest client call, what should i do?
for example in java with spring you put everything into an application.properties, so you and the framework can read from that file

Comment: i added the repository's url in the Answer, so you can check better the code